# How to keep size of struct unchanged in x32 and x64?

Tags: c, memory-management, padding

So I have a structure with mixed data types like the below and I want to make sure that sizeof(struct a) is a multiple of the word size in x32 and x64. How can I do that? Thank you.

```
struct a {
    vaddr_t v1;
    size_t v2;
    unsigned short v3; 
    struct b* v4; 
    struct a *v5;
    int v6;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Mysticial This is kind of data structure padding, for performance reason.

Comment: The compiler already does the optimal padding for you.

Comment: Is it your intent that the struct have the same binary layout on both 32- and 64-bit processes, e.g. to put it in shared memory? Or do you just want to ensure that it's naturally aligned without padding for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With basic types, like ints or shorts, you could achieve this by explicitly using int32 or int16 instead of int or short. For other types like size_t or pointers, it gets more complicated. Your best bet is to use type attributes (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html).

If all that matters is the structure alignment in memory, align the structure itself, not its members.

Answer (score 0):

I may be stepping a bit outside of my comfort zone here, however there seems to be a variation on the malloc called memalign thus :

```
 void *memalign(size_t alignment, size_t size);

 The memalign() function allocates size bytes on a  specified
 alignment  boundary  and  returns a pointer to the allocated
 block. The value of the returned address is guaranteed to be
 an  even  multiple of alignment. The value of alignment must
 be a power of two and must be greater than or equal  to  the
 size of a word.
```

That may or may not exist on all platforms but this one seems to be very common :

```
int posix_memalign(void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size);
```

Seen at :

```
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_memalign.html
```

Now I would think that the datatypes for fixed width type declarations, as proposed by the ISO/JTC1/SC22/WG14 C, committee's working draft for the revision of the current ISO C standard ISO/IEC 9899:1990 Programming language - C, ( I read that in a manpage ) would be cross platform and cross architecture stable.

So if you looked into the lower levels of your struct members then hopefully they are based on things like int32_t or uint32_t for an integer. There are POSIX types such as :

```
/*
 * POSIX Extensions
 */
typedef unsigned char   uchar_t;
typedef unsigned short  ushort_t;
typedef unsigned int    uint_t;
typedef unsigned long   ulong_t;
```

So I am thinking here that perhaps it is possible to construct your structs using only types that are defined as these totally cross platform stable datatypes and the end result being that the structs are always the same size regardless where or how you compile your code.

Please bear in mind, I am making a stretch here and hoping that someone else may clarify and perhaps correct my thinking.

Comment: While an int will be 4 bytes on most architectures for most compilers, a few of them will use 8 bytes for ints. But that's not the worst: pointers will use 8 bytes on 64 bits platforms vs. 4 on 32 bits ones. That's where may need padding and/or aligning. You are however right to mention memalign() since malloc doesn't care about type alignment...